# VLC Android 11 Screen Recording Playback

Tags: windows-10, vlc-media-player

I made a clip on my Pixel 3a using native Android 11 Screen Recording. I can play the clip on my phone and the capture shows all touch gestures, screen updates, etc.

I uploaded the file to Google Drive and playback using the Preview feature works as expected. However, when I download the clip to my Windows 10 desktop and play it with VLC 3.0.11, it appears to be dropping frames, or something, as many touch gestures and screen updates are not appearing.

The downloaded clip plays normally in both GOM and Pot Player. I can even drag the file into Chrome browser and it plays normally.

Never seen anything like this before with VLC. Any idea what might be wrong here?

UPDATE: ffprobe reports the following:

```
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'screen-20201104-073859.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: isommp42
    creation_time   : 2020-11-04T14:38:59.000000Z
    com.android.version: 11
  Duration: 00:00:35.96, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 6064 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1080x2220, 5974 kb/s, SAR 1:1 DAR 18:37, 12.63 fps, 90k tbr, 90k tbn, 180k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2020-11-04T14:38:59.000000Z
      handler_name    : VideoHandle
```

Comment: What does VLC state is the codec and bitrate? Is hardware video decoding enabled?

Comment: Codec: H264 - MPEG-4 AVC (part 10) (avc1). No bitrate reported on Codec tab. Hardware decoding is automatic (default).